# Get the id value PHP, mysql, jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to get the **ID** value in the `department_tbl` and put it in the `TextBox` instead of `Alert`.

```
<select name="departmentlvl" id="departmentlvl">
    <option value="" >Choose Department Level</option>
    <?php
        $qry="Select * from department_tbl";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            extract($row);
            echo "<option value='".$department_id."'>".$departmentDesc."
         </option>";

        }
    ?> 
</select>
<input type="text" id="" value="">// put the id value here($department_id)

//jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#departmentlvl").on('change', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a id attribute for the input field i.e

```
 <input type="text" id="department_id" value="">
```

On the jquery function just put the value

```
//jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#departmentlvl").on('change', function () {
    $("#department_id").val($(this).val());
  });});
```

Comment: glad... i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you can give id or name to text field and later access it using the same
e.g

```
<input type="text" name="myfirstinput" id="firstinput" />

//using name
$("input[name=myfirstinput]").val("demo");

//using id 
$("#firstinput").val("demo");
```